# Importing BitBucket git repository to Team Foundation Server 2018

Tags: tfs, bitbucket

When I create a new Git repository in a TFS project area, there are several options to add some code.

I’ve tried the import a repository a couple of times now.

The first run gave me this error after an extended period of time. This would indicate a connection timeout based on my experience with other tools and process.

[image]

We checked the logs in the EventViewer on the application server side but couldnt find anything.  We suspect an SSL/cert issue between BitBucket and TFS 2018.  This is also hosted in-house.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check whether the URL is correct. And please notice import service relies on **basic authentication** to communicate with the source repository. If the username / password you are using are not basic auth then authentication will fail and import will fail. One way to check if the username / password you are using are basic auth or not is to try using Git to clone your repository using the below format:

```
git clone https://<<username>>:<<password>>@<<remaining clone Url>>
```

Please refer to the following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts#frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We have confirmed that the test format works when cloning the repo.  We also tried SSH with keys.  Could proxy be at play?  Since this is a corporate setup.  Any ideas on how to  bypass by hostname setting?

Comment: Are you able to clone the BitBucket git repository manually on your build agent machine?